# Is it possible to create Solr Indexes via command prompt?

Tags: java, apache, solr, indexing, solrj

I want to know How to create Solr indexes through Command Prompt...?

If my apache_solr is configured at remote machine and I can not able to run browser there...so if I want to create indexes, How can I do that?

I have one servlet which can do the indexing but I want to know is it possible through command prompt or there are any other way to do the same...?
Thanks...

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/justengland/Solr-Command-Utility could help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With curl you can issue command directly from commandline like

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/db/dataimport?command=full-import
```

If you want you can wrap this into small bash scripts and put it under /usr/local/bin. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/db/dataimport?command=$1
```

This way you can issue command from commandline:

```
$ my-indexing-script.sh full-import
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [Solr 4.0 Beta Release](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/solrnews.html#14-august-2012-apache-solr-40-beta-available). As the new Admin Console in Solr 4.0 provides direct access to a majority of the API functions to create cores, load data, manage our indexes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need any browser to work with your Solr-Server. I would recommend to use the http API with any programming language or script you want. Using shell command isn´t really nice (well...at least for me). There are many libraries to handle http requests or if you really want to use a command prompt you can do it through http://curl.haxx.se/.

Answer (score 0):

E:\SolrRestInteraction\solr-4.2.1\example\exampledocs>java -Durl=http://"ip address":8983/solr/update/extract -Dparams=literal.id=Technology   -Dtype=text/html -ja
r post.jar Technology.html

Here i am providing the comad pompt solution  where "literal.id " is the unique id for html file to be indexed and finally you need to provide the html file name.  The above directory structure is with respect to my windows machine where "solr-4.2.1" is the down loaded  folder ...Any kind of issue u facing please let me know..
Dis will be done after starting the solr instance